# How to write query for Dynamic Date period slab / Grouped in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I want to create a report in which i need to show aggregate functions against the records in a 13 day period.

i.e

```
1. 2018-10-01  to 2018-10-13       17 count 
2. 2018-10-14  to 2018-10-26       9  count 
3. 2018-10-26  to 2018-11-09       65 count
......
```

need a dynamic query for any particular date range  like from 2018 to 2019 with slab of any number of days/months/year  like 17 days period slab within a provided range.

Comment: Can you provide some logic as to how to calculate the start / end date of a block, based on an X days period? Is it as simple as the earliest date being the origin and the periods start from there?

Comment: . suppose there are daily attendace record of students..... i want to see count atendance in a 5 days slab. table hav cols are >>> [date], [attendance_count] qerry out put should be like this ... startdate = '2018-06-01' ; period = 5; --slab of 5 days in the duration enddate = '2018-06-25'; 2 june 2018 to 7 june2018 71 8 june 2018 to 11 june2018 54 12 june 2018 to 18 june2018 77 19 june 2018 to 24 june2018 67

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just include date arithmetic in the aggregation:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, @startdate, min(date)) / @period, @startdate) as period_start,
       dateadd(day, @period - 1 + datediff(day, @startdate, min(date)) / @period, @startdate) as period_end,
       count(*)
from t
where date >= @startdate and date < @enddate
group by datediff(day, @startdate, date) / @period;
```

In SQL Server, I think `apply` makes this easier to follow:

```
select dateadd(day, periodnum * period, @startdate) as period_start,
       dateadd(day, periodnum * (period + 1) - 1, @startdate) as period_end,
       count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (datediff(day, @startdate, date) / @period)
     ) v(periodnum)
where date >= @startdate and date < @enddate
group by periodnum;
```

Comment: you are nearly getting my point , but your provided solution didnt work out in my case.

suppose there  are daily attendace record of students..... i want  to see avg atendance in a 5 days slab.

table hav cols are >>> [date], [attendance_count]

qerry out put should be like this ...

 startdate = '2018-06-01' ; 
 period = 5; --slab of 5  days in the duration
 enddate = '2018-06-25';

 2 june 2018 to 7 june2018       71
8 june 2018 to 11 june2018       54
12 june 2018 to 18 june2018       77
19 june 2018 to 24 june2018       67

Comment: @NabeelArif . . . This question is about counts and not averages.  If you have a question about averages, then ask *another* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: sorry it's the count of attendance  in dynamic period slab